# forloop img src is /no-image

Tags: shopify, liquid

Trying to pull images into a into a wrapper after assigning a specific collection but my images are all returning - //cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/no-image

```
<div id="NewColorOptions" class="color-select">
  {% assign color_options = '' %}
  {% for collection in collections %}
    {% if product.handle contains collection.handle %}
      {% assign collection = collection.handle %}
      {% for p in collection.products %}
        {% assign p_handle = '--' | append: p.handle | append: '--' %}
        {% if color_options contains p_handle %}
              {% comment %} Probably Duplicates {% endcomment %}
        {% else %}
            {% assign color_options = color_options | append: p_handle %}
            {% assign product_text = p.title | handleize | remove : collection.handle | replace : '-', ' ' %}
              <a href="{{ p.url }}" datattitle="{{ product_text | textilize | upcase }}" {% if p.url contains product.handle %}class="ActiveThumb"{%endif%}>

                <img {% if forloop.first == true %} class="imgOne" {% endif %} src="{{ image.src | product_img_url: 'compact' }}">

              </a>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

I assume my error is within my `<img>` tag but I'm not sure why that would be breaking.

Comment: Where do you define `image` ? You are calling `image.src`, but I don't see where is the `image` object defined.

Comment: isn't {{ image.src }} part of shopify's object model? or do I need to assign it first?

Comment: Solved, I added p.featured_image into the img src attr and now it is outputting correctly.